# How to create generics with the schema language?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server

Using facebook's reference library, I found a way to hack generic types like this:

```js
type PagedResource<Query, Item> = (pagedQuery: PagedQuery<Query>) => PagedResponse<Item>
    ​
interface PagedQuery<Query> {
  query: Query;
  take: number;
  skip: number;
}
    ​
interface PagedResponse<Item> {
  items: Array<Item>; 
  total: number;
}
```

---

```js
function pagedResource({type, resolve, args}) {
  return {
    type: pagedType(type),
    args: Object.assign(args, {
      page: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(pageQueryType()) }
    }),
    resolve
  };
  function pageQueryType() {
    return new GraphQLInputObjectType({
      name: 'PageQuery',
      fields: {
        skip: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt) },
        take: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt) }
      }
    });
  }
  function pagedType(type) {
    return new GraphQLObjectType({
      name: 'Paged' + type.toString(),
      fields: {
        items: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(new GraphQLList(type))},
        total: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt) }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

But I like how with Apollo Server I can declaratively create the schema. So question is, how do you guys go about creating generic-like types with the schema language?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create an interface or union to achieve a similar result. I think [this article](https://medium.com/the-graphqlhub/graphql-tour-interfaces-and-unions-7dd5be35de0d) does a good job explaining how to implement interfaces and unions correctly. Your schema would look something like this:

```
type Query {
  pagedQuery(page: PageInput!): PagedResult
}

input PageInput {
  skip: Int!
  take: Int!
}

type PagedResult {
  items: [Pageable!]!
  total: Int
}

# Regular type definitions for Bar, Foo, Baz types...

union Pageable = Bar | Foo | Baz
```

You also need to define a resolveType method for the union. With `graphql-tools`, this is done through the resolvers:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: { ... },
  Pageable {
    __resolveType: (obj) => {
      // resolve logic here, needs to return a string specifying type
      // i.e. if (obj.__typename == 'Foo') return 'Foo'
    }
  }
}
```

`__resolveType` takes the business object being resolved as its first argument (typically your raw DB result that you give GraphQL to resolve). You need to apply some logic here to figure out of all the different Pageable types, which one we're handling. With most ORMs, you can just add some kind of `typename` field to the model instance you're working with and just have `resolveType` return that.

**Edit:** As you pointed out, the downside to this approach is that the returned type in items is no longer transparent to the client -- the client would have to know what type is being returned and specify the fields for `items` within an inline fragment like `... on Foo`. Of course, your clients will still have to have some idea about what type is being returned, otherwise they won't know what fields to request.

I imagine creating generics the way you want is impossible when generating a schema declaratively. To get your schema to work the same way it currently does, you would have to bite the bullet and define `PagedFoo` when you define `Foo`, define `PagedBar` when you define `Bar` and so on.

The only other alternative I can think of is to combine the two approaches. Create your "base" schema programatically. You would only need to define the paginated queries under the Root Query using your `pagedResource` function. You can then use `printSchema` from `graphql/utilities` to convert it to a String that can be concatenated with the rest of your type definitions. Within your type definitions, you can use the `extend` keyword to build on any of the types already declared in the base schema, like this:

```
extend Query {
  nonPaginatedQuery: Result
}
```

If you go this route, you can skip passing a `resolve` function to `pagedResource`, or defining any resolvers on your programatically-defined types, and just utilize the resolvers object you normally pass to `buildExecutableSchema`.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that the client will need to figure out what type is being returned?

Comment: Yeah, the client would have to use inline fragments. Not sure if there's a good way of doing what you're trying to accomplish without generating the schema programatically. See my edit for some additional thoughts.

Comment: Appreciate the effort